# Does hibernation data persist without power?

Tags: windows-7, power, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

My office shuts down power every weekend while I generally like to keep things open and all set to go for Monday. If I hibernate on Friday, will the hibernation state persist without power so I can resume on Monday?

If not, is there a utility to make this possible?

If so, can I schedule my machine to automatically hibernate at a certain time on Friday?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hibernation will allow all your data and programs to be restored after a loss of power.

Hibernation is a power-saving state designed primarily for laptops. While sleep puts your work and settings in memory and draws a small amount of power, hibernation puts your open documents and programs on your hard disk, and then *turns off* your computer. Of all the power-saving states in Windows, hibernation uses the least amount of power - none! On a laptop, use hibernation when you know that you won't use your laptop for an extended period and won't have an opportunity to charge the battery during that time.

Comment: Any response to being able to schedule hibernation at a set time?

Comment: @Enigma supposedly `Shutdown /h` will do it. See `Shutdown /?`.

Comment: Can that command be integrated with a task scheduler?

Comment: yes it can.  You can also set your computers power button to go into hibernation when pressed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it persists..If you hibernate all data of your machine state is stored in **hiberfile.sys** in your drive containing windows ...!
[image: hiberfile.sys]

**So What is hiberfil.sys Anyway?**

Windows has two power management modes that you can choose from: one is Sleep Mode, which keeps the PC running in a low power state so you can almost instantly get back to what you were working on. The other is Hibernate mode, which completely writes the memory out to the hard drive, and then powers the PC down entirely, so you can even take the battery out, put it back in, start back up, and be right back where you were.

Hibernate mode uses the hiberfil.sys file to store the the current state (memory) of the PC, and since it’s managed by Windows, you can’t delete the file.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15140/what-is-hiberfil.sys-and-how-do-i-delete-it/)